# jQuery Datepicker - Set 1st picker to limit to active week of 2nd picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

Two datepickers, staff are to enter a weekday into datepicker 1 (#from) and then enter in a second date into (#to). Date 2 must always be in the future with respect to date 1. Weekends not allowed.

working example of this, excluding weekends, and not allowing  past dates in date 2, is available in this fiddle:

**https://jsfiddle.net/gLrumpo3/6/**

```
<input id="from">
<input id="to"> 

$("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    onSelect: function(dateStr)
    {
        $("#to").val(dateStr);
        $("#to").datepicker("option",{ minDate: new Date(dateStr)})
    }
  });

$('#to').datepicker({
   defaultDate: new Date(),
   beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
   onSelect: function(dateStr) {
     toDate = new Date(dateStr);
     fromDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(fromDate);
     toDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(toDate);
   }
 });
```

Waht I need now though, is to be able to "lock" the 2nd date input to the same WEEK as the first date, I thought about ising maxDate, but I can only specifiy an arbitrary offset, like Xdays, or a specific date. This is no good as people may select thursday for example, i cant then add 4 days to it and set it as max date, as they would be able to select monday next week.

So how can i constrain their date inouts to one week, where that week is set absed on the day selected of the 1st field.

Please update fiddle with working answers if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
$( "#to" ).datepicker("option",{minDate: new Date(dateStr), maxDate:endDate});
```

You can set `maxDate` to last date of that week for `$( "#to" )` datepicker.

```js
$("#from").datepicker({
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  minDate: new Date(),
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  onSelect: function(dateStr)
  {
      $("#to").val(dateStr);
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
         endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
      $( "#to" ).datepicker("option",{minDate: new Date(dateStr), maxDate:endDate});
      
  }
});

$('#to').datepicker({
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    toDate = new Date(dateStr);
    //fromDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(fromDate);
    //toDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(toDate);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="from">
<input id="to">
```

Comment: That works perfectly, upvoted and answer accepted. Thankyou.

Comment: Glad to help you:)